# Right-click, curser interaction issues, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, hp, interface

Running Ubuntu 18.04.5 on HP EliteBook. Seemingly at random my curser has stopped interacting with much of the interface/screen & my right clickbutton has stopped working entirely with right click on the touchpad working intermittently/randomly. Tried Gnome Tweaks & other solutions suggested online with no help.
If I close the laptop & let it go to sleep it sometimes de-bugs for one or two click of the touchpad before losing interaction again.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is a hardware problem - a loose connection on the touchpad?
Are you only running Ubuntu on this machine, or can you boot into another OS? Does the problem also exist on that other OS?

If you are not running another OS on the laptop, maybe try to make a USB/DVD "live CD" of a distribution that you can try without installing ([Ubuntu 20.04 USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started) will allow this). Then see if your problem exists on the live distribution.

Good luck :)